# In Android, using the same toolbar (RelativeLayout elements) across multiple views

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm in the process of writing a toolbar in one of my views via XML - a toolbar that will be cloned in multiple views.  Is there anyway I can reference the same XML in all my views, as opposed to copying and pasting the code?  Am I forced to use a Fragment or can I programmatically add the same XML?

Comment: There is something known as **Styles** in Android, see if that is what your are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the include tag:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

**Edit:**

Looks like the link above is now dead, here's a working one:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html